# UserDefault To Save Button State

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to complete my favorite button by saving it state even when i     quit the view \ App . it will be great if anyone could show me how can i do 
this, I'm using Xcode 8 and coding with Swift 3.

```
  //create a new button
    let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
    //set image for button
    Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
    Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), for: .selected)
    //add function for button
    Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button), for: .touchUpInside)
    //set frame
    Favoritebutton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 35,height: 35)

    Favoritebutton.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved")

    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
    //assign button to navigationbar

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton

    let state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved") ?? false

    }


@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    if let Favoritebutton = sender as? UIButton {
        Favoritebutton.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved")
        if Favoritebutton.isSelected {
            // set selected
            Favoritebutton.isSelected = true



    // set badge Value to tabbar item.
    let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3]
    sel_val = tabItem?.badgeValue
    if(sel_val == nil){
        sel_val = "0"
    }
    let sel_num  = Int(sel_val!)
    tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! + 1) as String
    //Add Favorite
    let Fav: NSMutableArray = []
    Fav.add(barImage)
    Fav.add(barName)
    Fav.add(streetName)
    favorite.add(Fav)




        } else {
            // set deselected
            Favoritebutton.isSelected = false
            //Badge Value Count.
            let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3]
            sel_val = tabItem?.badgeValue
            if(sel_val == nil){
                sel_val = "0"
            }
            let sel_num  = Int(sel_val!)
            tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! - 1) as String
            //Remove Favorite
            let Fav: NSMutableArray = []
            Fav.add(barImage)
            Fav.add(barName)
            Fav.add(streetName)
            favorite.remove(Fav)


        }
    }
```

Comment: You are saving the state but you need to read it back in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: How can i do this please? @vadian

Comment: Your code only ever saves a key "isSaved" as true. You never wrote code to load or save the selected state of your button. See @Scinfu's answer for code that loads and saves the selected state of your button to `UserDefaults`.

Comment: @DuncanC You are saying Scinifu's Code is correct? and vadian saying its not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can reduce the code in `button` to

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "isSaved")
}
```

To set the state you have to read it back

```
let Favoritebutton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
//set image for button
Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), for: .selected)
Favoritebutton.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved")
...
```

Edit:

I have no clue what your code does but there is a lot of redundant code. The `IBAction` can be reduced to (untested, of course)

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {

    let newValue = !sender.isSelected
    sender.isSelected = newValue
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "isSaved")

    let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3]
    sel_val = tabItem?.badgeValue
    if(sel_val == nil){
        sel_val = "0"
    }
    let sel_num  = Int(sel_val!)

    let fav: NSMutableArray = []
    fav.add(barImage)
    fav.add(barName)
    fav.add(streetName)
    if sender.isSelected {
        tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! + 1)
        favorite.add(fav)
    } else {
        tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! - 1)
        favorite.remove(fav)
    }
}
```

and please name variables with a starting lowercase letter.

Comment: look i updated my question with full code....now my button `isSelected` all the time can you match it to my full code ?

Comment: Your code is very very confusing. You should describe **exactly** what the code is supposed to do. For instance what is `MY_FAV_KEY` for?

Comment: Updated Code...Can you Make this Code save the button state?

Comment: ok listen now it saves the button state but it doesn't differentiate between cells ...like it doesn't recognize indexPath

Comment: If it saves the state the question is answered. Your question doesn't mention anything about cells and index paths.

Comment: Very Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use `UserDefaults.standard.set` you need sync , add `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()`.

To remove/delete a saved value use `UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "YOUR_KEY")`

here is your func

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected


    //one thing i tried , doesn't work :
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true,forKey: "isSaved")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()


    if let Favoritebutton = sender as? UIButton {
        if Favoritebutton.isSelected {
            // set selected
            Favoritebutton.isSelected = true
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "MY_FAV_KEY")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            //Add to favorites

        } else {
            // set deselected
            Favoritebutton.isSelected = false
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "MY_FAV_KEY")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
            //remove from Favorites

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not working.....when i press the button and it becomes selected and then i quite the view its still does not save the button state....any other idea how to make it work?

Comment: *You do **not** need sync.*