# Maintaining Button State when App is Re-opened with Swift/Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I am new to Swift and Xcode, but I have been reading on here and watching videos on YouTube to guide me along with starting my app. I can't seem to get my button to save its state once the app is closed and re-opened. I used [UserDefault To Save Button State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429699/userdefault-to-save-button-state) as an example, but following it still did not get the button state saved.

I set the state with the Interface Builder and so far have the below code:

```
@IBAction func ownedButton(_ sender UIButton) {

sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "isSaved")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Clicking the button will keep it selected until clicked again, so it is partially working. It looks like I need some code to in the viewDidLoad section, but I haven't been able to figure out what it should be.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I recommend saving your data locally whenever the button's state changes as you will lose the state once app quits

Answer (score 0):

A habit from my Objective-C days is to write a wrapper around the properties in `UserDefaults`. This way, everything is compile-time checked and the use of strings as keys is minimized:

```
// Properties.swift
import Foundation

fileprivate var standardDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

class Properties {
    static func registerDefaults() {
        standardDefaults.register(defaults: [
            kIsButton1Selected: false,
            kIsButton2Selected: true
        ])
    }

    fileprivate static let kIsButton1Selected = "isButton1Selected"
    static var isButton1Selected: Bool {
        get { return standardDefaults.value(forKey: kIsButton1Selected) as! Bool }
        set { standardDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: kIsButton1Selected) }
    }

    fileprivate static let kIsButton2Selected = "isButton2Selected"
    static var isButton2Selected: Bool {
        get { return standardDefaults.value(forKey: kIsButton2Selected) as! Bool }
        set { standardDefaults.set(newValue, forKey: kIsButton2Selected) }
    }
}
```

Then in your View Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Always call registerDefaults before you use UserDefaults
    // for the first time in your app
    Properties.registerDefaults()
    button1.isSelected = Properties.isButton1Selected
    button2.isSelected = Properties.isButton2Selected
}

@IBAction func ownedButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    switch sender {
    case button1:
        Properties.isButton1Selected = sender.isSelected
    case button2:
        Properties.isButton2Selected = sender.isSelected
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

You can replace the `switch` with key-value observing but remember to remove the KVO on `deinit`.

Comment: The error I get when I do this says "Use of unresolved identifier 'button1'" and the same thing for 'button2'

Comment: Of course you have to change the name to whatever name you give the IBOutlet