# NSButton value as default in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, nsbutton

I am a newbie in swift using **Xcode** trying to write a small checklist app. After I **check/uncheck** the checkbox and exit the app, the state just disappears next time when I reopen it next time. I am wondering how can I save the current state of *NSButton* as default so that next time when I open the app, it will show up the same state when I closed it. I tried below practice:

Set default value:

```
@IBAction func Check1(_ sender: NSButton) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(Check1.state, forKey:"Check1status")
    }
```

Read default value:

```
override var representedObject: Any? {
    didSet {
        Check1.state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"Check1status")
    }
}
```

However I received error message:"Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'NSControl.StateValue'"

How can I fix this error? Thanks.

Comment: Check out UserDefaults. https://stackoverflow.com/q/31203241/3151675

Comment: check this one more clear according your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429699/userdefault-to-save-button-state

Comment: I received error message: "Value of type 'NSButton' has no member 'isSelected'" when I tried to use SelfKey.isSelected. Should I use another member in NSButton?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UserDefault To Save Button State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429699/userdefault-to-save-button-state)

Comment: isSelected==true is state==NSOnState

Comment: isSelected==false is state==NSOffState

Comment: When I tried to set default value SelfKey.state = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "State") after I set: UserDefaults.standard.set(SelfKey.state, forKey:"State"), I received error: "Cannot assign value of type 'Bool' to type 'NSControl.StateValue". What should I use other than UserDefaults.standard.bool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `state` is not a boolean value. In Objective-C, it's an integer. In Swift, it's a [struct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol.statevalue) whose `rawValue` is an integer. Also, don't set the state in `representedObject.didSet`. Do it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // When your app launches for the very first time on the user computer, set it to On
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: [
        "Check1Status": NSControl.StateValue.on.rawValue
    ])

    let state = NSControl.StateValue(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey:"Check1status"))
    check1.state = state
}

@IBAction func check1(_ sender: NSButton) {
    // Swift performs do some background magic if you type check1.state
    // Adding rawValue make it clear that you are writing an integer to the UserDefaults
    UserDefaults.standard.set(check1.state.rawValue, forKey:"Check1status")
}
```