# Is there a way to save 'selected' state of a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I'm creating a jigsaw puzzle app for kids with 24 different little puzzles in 24 different scenes. I've put the background music in a Singleton, like so:

```swift
class MusicHelper { static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper() var audioPlayerBGM: AVAudioPlayer?
    func playBackgroundMusic() {
        let BGM = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jigsawBGM", ofType: "wav")!)
        do {
            audioPlayerBGM = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:BGM as URL)
            audioPlayerBGM!.numberOfLoops = -1
            audioPlayerBGM!.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayerBGM!.play()
            audioPlayerBGM!.volume = 0.1
        } catch {
            print("Cannot play the file")
        }
    }
    
    func pauseBackgroundMusic() {
        let BGM = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jigsawBGM", ofType: "wav")!)
        do {
            audioPlayerBGM = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:BGM as URL)
            audioPlayerBGM!.pause()
        } catch {
            print("Cannot play the file")
        }
    }
}
```

For the sake of parents' sanity, I've also written a snippet of code to mute the BGM. Like so:

```
@IBOutlet weak var muteMusicButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func muteMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
 
    if muteMusicButton.isSelected {
        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.pauseBackgroundMusic()
    } else {
        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic()
    }
}
```

I've put the muteMusicButton in a separate view controller scene (like a 'controls' or 'settings' window for the app user). It's a custom button with different images for default state ('music on' image) and selected state ('music off' image).
The problem is that the button resets to default state when its view controller is dismissed, so that when you access the view controller again music is still paused, but the button displays the 'music on' image, and you have to press it twice to start the music again.

Is there a way to make to make a button 'remember' its selected state when you dismiss/re-access its view controller?
(UserDefault perhaps, which I am notoriously incompetent at!)

Or should I go about the whole thing in a completely different manner?

Comment: UserDefaultS is good solution here imo since the app then can “remember” the state the next time it is opened

Comment: Yes, it probably is a good solution, I'm just really rubbish at it. I've looked at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429699/userdefault-to-save-button-state?rq=3 but nothing is working for me. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @KrisP - are you already saving the user's *selection* between app uses? That is, if the user turns off the music, have you already coded your app so the music is *already turned off* the next time it is run?

Comment: @DonMag: No. Would that not be done with UserDefault as well? Like I said, I'm rubbish at UserDefault - but I'm reading up on it now. I've decided not to let it win :-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying *"I'm rubbish at UserDefault"* take a little time to **learn about it**.

Very briefly, though...

Decide on a "key" for your setting -- let's use "isMuted"

When you're going to **start** playing music, read the value of that key from `UserDefaults`:

```
let b: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
if b {
    // don't play the music
} else {
    // play the music
}
```

When you show your "settings" view controller (in `viewDidLoad` for example), read that value and set the button's `isSelected` property:

```
let b: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
muteMusicButton.isSelected = b
```

When the user taps the button, write the new value to `UserDefaults` (based on your code):

```
@IBAction func muteMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isSelected, forKey: "isMuted")
    
    if muteMusicButton.isSelected {

        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.pauseBackgroundMusic()
    }

    else {

        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic()
    }
}
```

Comment: Get off your high horse and read the comment where I said I'm reading up on it!

Comment: @KrisP - sorry... I intended for that to sound *encouraging*, not critical.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like would be best to read the `isPlaying` property at `viewWillAppear` of the `ViewController` to update the button state accordingly.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioplayer/1390139-isplaying

```swift
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
   muteMusicButton.selected = !MusicHelper.sharedHelper.audioPlayerBGM.isPlaying
}
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything ...

Comment: Updated: You need to overwrite the lifecycle method...

Comment: You must call `super.viewWillAppear(animated)` inside the overridden method.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to store a `Bool` to UserDefaults:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isMuted")
```

Use this to read back your `Bool`:

```
let isMuted = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
```

In your example:

```
class MusicHelper {
    static let sharedHelper = MusicHelper()
    var audioPlayerBGM: AVAudioPlayer?

    init() {
        let BGM = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jigsawBGM", ofType: "wav")!)
        audioPlayerBGM = try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: BGM)
        audioPlayerBGM?.numberOfLoops = -1
        audioPlayerBGM?.volume = 0.1
        audioPlayerBGM?.prepareToPlay()

         let isMuted = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isMuted") // here
         if !isMuted {
             audioPlayerBGM?.play()
         }
    }

    func playBackgroundMusic() {
        audioPlayerBGM?.play()
    }

    func pauseBackgroundMusic() {
        audioPlayerBGM?.pause()
    }
}
```

```
@IBOutlet weak var muteMusicButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func muteMusic(_ sender: UIButton) {

    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
 
    if muteMusicButton.isSelected {
        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.pauseBackgroundMusic()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isMuted")  // here
     } else {
        MusicHelper.sharedHelper.playBackgroundMusic()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isMuted")  // here
     }
}
```

```
func viewWillAppear() {
   muteMusicButton.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isMuted")
}
```